# How to store / load exported environment variables to / from a file

Tags: environment-variables, persistence

I would like to be able to save my current environment in a file (for a running interactive session), so that I can:

- Save it, export/modify/delete variables at will in the running session, then restore the saved environment
- Switch at will between multiple environment
- Detect differences between two environment

I am only interested in exported variables. As I want to be able to restore the environment it have to be a shell function, I am using bash. Ideally, it would not depends on external programs, and would work on versions of bash from v3.2.25 to current.

For now, to save my environment I use the following function:

```
env_save () {
    export -p > "$STORAGE/$1.sh"
}
```

That I use as `env_save <filename>` in a running session. I have some boilerplate code to keep backups, but let's ignore that.

However, I then have difficulties with loading the environment back:

```
env_restore () {
    source "$STORAGE/$1.sh"
}
```

As this would not remove spurious variables that I created in the mean time. That is, calling `export -p` after `env_restore <filename>` might not give the same output than `cat $STORAGE/$1.sh`.

Is there a clean way to handle that problem? I will probably need to blacklist some variables such as PWD, OLDPWD, SHELL, SHLVL, USER, SSH_*, STORAGE, etc... That is, those variable should not be saved and should not be changed when restoring as they are special variables. I cannot use a whitelist as I do not know what variables will be there.

Comment: Does the env(1) command do what you want? The `export` command is a shell builtin that, as far as I know, is not well suited to your use. You want may want something simpler like env(1), which does not interact with your shell.

Comment: env(1) would be fine. My problem is how to load back the environment. I need to clean it up, somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POSIXly, you can do:

```
# save
export -p > saved-env

...

# restore
blacklisted () {
  case $1 in
    PWD|OLDPWD|SHELL|STORAGE|-*) return 0 ;;
    *) return 1 ;;
  esac
}

eval '
  export() {
    blacklisted "${1%%=*}" || unset -v "${1%%=*}"
  }
  '"$(export -p)"
export() {
  blacklisted "${1%%=*}" || command export "$@"
}
. saved-env
unset -f export
```

Note that for `bash` not invoked as `sh`, you'd need to issue a `set -o posix` for that to work properly. Also with `bash` versions prior to 4.4, sourcing the output of `export -p` is potentially unsafe:

```
$ env -i 'a;reboot;=1' /bin/bash -o posix -c 'export -p'
export OLDPWD
export PWD="/"
export SHLVL="1"
export a;reboot;
```

ksh93 has a similar problem. `yash` doesn't have that particular one, but still has problems with variable names starting with `-`:

```
$ env -i -- '-p=' yash -c 'export -p'
export '-p'=''
export OLDPWD
export PWD='/'
```

Also beware of potential problems if you're not in the same locale when saving and restoring the variables.

```
bash-4.3$ locale charmap
ISO-8859-15
bash-4.3$ export Stéphane=1
bash-4.3$ export -p > a
bash-4.3$ LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 bash -c '. ./a'
./a: line 5: export: `Stéphane=1': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: @cuonglm the asker specifically mentioned blacklisting `STORAGE` along with other env variables not normally set by the user.

Comment: @Dave Oh, the question was updated,

Comment: Excellent remarks about the pitfalls. I more or less assumed the environment variables where in a correct format, but that is how security problems are created!

Comment: A couple bourne shells I tried don't like overloading 'export' as a custom function.  dash: 1: Syntax error: Bad function name.  FreeBSD sh: Syntax error: Cannot override a special builtin with a function.

Comment: Trying to overload export() doesn't work with mksh, pdksh and zsh either.  Invoking 'export' after defining a custom export() function just runs the builtin export.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way by using `compgen -A export` to get the list of environment variables:

```
blacklisted () {
    case $1 in
        PWD|OLDPWD|SHELL|STORAGE) return 0 ;;
        *) return 1 ;;
    esac
}

env_save () { # Assume "$STORAGE/#1.sh" is empty
    local VAR
    for VAR in $(compgen -A export); do
        blacklisted $VAR || \
            echo "export $VAR='${!VAR}'" >> "$STORAGE/$1.sh"
    done
}

env_restore () {
    local VAR
    for VAR in $(compgen -A export); do
        blacklisted $VAR || \
            unset $VAR
    done
    source "$STORAGE/$1.sh"
}
```

Comment: This is sadly `bash` specific, maybe somebody can come up with a better solution.